# Calculate average and normalize GPS data in Python

Tags: python, json, filter, gps, calculation

I have a dataset in json with gps coordinates:

```
"utc_date_and_time":"2021-06-05 13:54:34", # timestamp
"hdg":"018.0",                             # heading
"sog":"000.0",                             # speed
"lat":"5905.3262N",                        # latitude
"lon":"00554.2433E"                        # longitude
```

This data will be imported into a database, with one entry every second for every "vessel".
As you can imagine this is a huge amount of data that provides a level of accuracy I do not need.

**My goal:**

- Create a new entry in the database for every X seconds
- If I set X to 60 (a minute) and there are missing 10 entries within this period, 50 entries should be used. Data can be missing for certain periods, and I do not want this to create bogus positions.
- Use timestamp from last entry in period.
- Use the heading (hdg) that is appearing the most times within this period.
- Calculate average speed within this period.
- Latitude and longitude could use the last entry, but I have seen "spikes" that needs to be filtered out, or use average, and remove values that differ too much.

My script is now pushing all the data to the database via a for loop with different data-checks inside it, and this is working.
I am new to python and still learning every day through reading and youtube videos, but it would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction for how to achieve the above goal.

As of now the data is imported into a dictionary. And I am wondering if creating a dictionary where the timestamp is the key is the way to go, but I am a little lost.

Code:

```
import os
import json
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

def generator(data):
    for entry in data:
        yield entry

data = json.load(open("5_gps_2021-06-05T141524.1397180000.json"))["gps_data"]
gps_count = len(data)

start_time = None
new_gps = list()
tempdata = list()
seconds = 60
i = 0

for entry in generator(data):
    i = i+1
    if start_time == None:
        start_time = datetime.fromisoformat(entry['utc_date_and_time'])
    # TODO: Filter out values with too much deviation
    tempdata.append(entry)
    elapsed = (datetime.fromisoformat(entry['utc_date_and_time']) - start_time).total_seconds()
    if (elapsed >= seconds) or (i == gps_count):
        # TODO: Calculate average values etc. instead of using last
        new_gps.append(tempdata)
        tempdata = []
        start_time = None

print("GPS count before:" + str(gps_count))
print("GPS count after:" + str(len(new_gps)))
```

Output:

```
GPS count before:1186
GPS count after:20
```

Comment: Please post the code relevant to your question.

Comment: Interesting project, but your question is a bit vague. It seems you do not have a specific problem, and this makes things difficult to answer. I would do few scripts: 1- a importer which log each entry in specific files (e.g. one per minute, maybe one per vessel) [maybe two: one realtime, one from old database]. 2- a cleaner (which read the files, do the average and logic of your question, so it handles not too much data, and not much filter needed, so no need to worry much about efficienct). It will import results in the new database.

Comment: I have added the code. These json files are uploaded from vessels to server all the time, so the parser code I'm writing needs to "compress" and filter the data before it is added to the database.